# onclick $(document.body).append() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

here i want to show bootstrap modal on onclick event. Onclick event alert() is coming but **$(document.body).append() (modal code)** is not initializing it seems... i am not getting any error in console also... 
this is my code...

```
    (function() {  
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.wpc', {  
    init : function(ed, url) { 
        ed.addButton('wpc', {  
            title : 'Add Contact Us form',  
            image : url+'/dd_note.gif', 
            onclick : function() {
                alert("hii"); // it's coming on onclick event

                $(document.body).append('<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <div class="modal-dialog"> <div class="modal-content"> <div class="modal-header"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Forms List</h4> </div> <div class="modal-body"> <script> showForms("'+url+'"); </script></div> <div class="modal-footer"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addForm()">Add Page</button> </div> </div> </div> </div>');

                $('#myModal').modal();
            }  
        });  
    },  
    createControl : function(n, cm) {  
        return null;  
    },  
});  
tinymce.PluginManager.add('wpc', tinymce.plugins.wpc);  
})();
```

can anyone suggest me what's going wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with `$('body').append()`

Comment: @SridharR i tried but no change

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM?

Comment: @BlackSheep just now i inspected DOM.. it's getting appended but i am not getting popup window

Comment: There should be a CSS issue, have you added Bootstrap's Modal CSS to the page? Can you scroll after calling `.modal()`?

Comment: Bootstrap file is loaded in head section that also i have inspected

Comment: Try with removing the `script` tag from the markup.

Answer (score 1):

In your html there are is script tag and some browsers does not allow to add it as text so u have to create script dom element from javascript and then append it or try something like this:

to replace in your appending html:

```
<script> showForms("'+url+'"); </script>
```

to:

```
<script> showForms("'+url+'");</' + 'script>
```

to allow browser to know that it is script tag.

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NKQ2z/20/) for appending this html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(function() {  
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.wpc', {  
    init : function(ed, url) { 
        ed.addButton('wpc', {  
            title : 'Add Contact Us form',  
            image : url+'/dd_note.gif', 
            onclick : function() {
                alert("hii"); // it's coming on onclick event

                $('body').append('<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <div class="modal-dialog"> <div class="modal-content"> <div class="modal-header"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Forms List</h4> </div> <div class="modal-body"> <script> showForms("'+url+'"); </script></div> <div class="modal-footer"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addForm()">Add Page</button> </div> </div> </div> </div>');

                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }  
        });  
    },  
    createControl : function(n, cm) {  
        return null;  
    },  
});  
tinymce.PluginManager.add('wpc', tinymce.plugins.wpc);  
})();
```

Comment: @404NotFound whar error you getting inspect body whether it s appended or not?

Comment: there is no error.. it's appending at last but not showing in popup

Comment: @404NotFound load all necessary js ,css files for bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap file is loaded in head section that also i have inspected